# QBO Payment Query returns 'unauthorized'

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

When I perform a search by LastUpdatedTime I get "401 Unauthorized Error". Query by CustomerId works fine

Here is my code:

```
var pq = new PaymentQuery()
{
    LastUpdatedTime = new DateTime(2012,12,21),
};

pq.SpecifyOperatorOption(Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.FilterProperty.LastUpdatedTime, FilterOperatorType.AFTER);
var list = pq.ExecuteQuery<Payment>(commonService.ServiceContext);
```

Application throws Intuit.Ipp.Exception.InvalidTokenException in ExecuteQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDK does not encode the datetime correctly, so you will need to use DevDefined and deserialize the response with the SDK.  Code sample:  https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/6024616

Comment: My token is fine.I can perform many other queries such as metioned PaymentQuery, but with CustomerId as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

What does the full error look like?
Are you able to do other calls fine with this company using the token sets & realm ID that you have in place?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to do any other calls - as I wrote, I can perform queries with only CustomerID as parameter, I can get sorted results.

Comment: Full error does not have any additional information - only "401 Unauthorized Error" as message